# mac: pyQt5 button click (connect method) doesn't respond instantly

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, freeze, qpushbutton

I am entirely new to pyQt5, and only recently started learning about different methods. I created a simple button that changes the label text when clicked using a connect method; however, somehow, it is not responding instantly.  The function that I called in my class worked only after taking specific actions, such as swiping to a different desktop, opening something irrelevant, for instance, a folder. So I couldn't see instant feedback as if it was frozen. (This was the same for a straightforward print statement as well. When I put print("clicked") inside the clicked method in MyWindow class, it didn't show on the console until I exited the window, and the process was finished.) I am using a MAC environment and a standard python3.7 in the sublime text editor. Please help me out to figure out how this can be fixed.

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow 
import sys 

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300) #sets position for window 
        self.setWindowTitle("pyQt5 learning")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Label")
        self.label.move(50, 50)

        self.bt1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.bt1.setText("Click")
        self.bt1.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

    def clicked(self):
        self.label.setText("You pressed the button!")
        self.label.adjustSize()

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

There is one additional question about a crash that happened when I made

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

run when the button was clicked. This crash happened in different circumstances as well, which I don't specifically remember. Would you please help me find out why this crash is being generated and what this means?

Crash:

```
Process:               Python [18927]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            org.python.python
Version:               3.7.0 (3.7.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        plugin_host [6565]
Responsible:           Sublime Text [6561]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-07-02 03:49:31.987 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.2 (19C57)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        1CC693FD-7CAB-7C0A-C8C5-0C48DF9F3893

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D483666A-39A0-452A-B5DC-3BE02AB7D78A

Time Awake Since Boot: 29000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       7400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010141d7fa __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010147abc1 pthread_kill + 432
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000010125ca1c abort + 120
3   QtCore                          0x0000000106a27989 qt_message_fatal(QtMsgType, QMessageLogContext const&, QString const&) + 9
4   QtCore                          0x0000000106a290d4 QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 202 (qlogging.cpp:893)
5   QtCore.abi3.so                  0x0000000114ee9e32 pyqt5_err_print() + 802
6   QtCore.abi3.so                  0x0000000114eefaa4 PyQtSlotProxy::unislot(void**) + 100
7   QtCore.abi3.so                  0x0000000114eefa0a PyQtSlotProxy::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 58
8   QtCore                          0x0000000106c3a2be void doActivate<false>(QObject*, int, void**) + 1118
9   QtWidgets                       0x0000000104675a1f QAbstractButtonPrivate::emitClicked() + 111 (qsharedpointer_impl.h:701)
10  QtWidgets                       0x0000000104675899 QAbstractButtonPrivate::click() + 233 (qabstractbutton.cpp:409)
11  QtWidgets                       0x0000000104676a4f QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) + 271 (qabstractbutton.cpp:1045)
12  QtWidgets.abi3.so               0x000000010412e9f9 sipQPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) + 121
13  QtWidgets                       0x00000001045c67bd QWidget::event(QEvent*) + 445 (qwidget.cpp:8653)
14  QtWidgets.abi3.so               0x000000010412f323 sipQPushButton::event(QEvent*) + 195
15  QtWidgets                       0x000000010458bfea QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 266 (qapplication.cpp:3673)
16  QtWidgets                       0x000000010458eec2 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 7330 (qapplication.cpp:3115)
17  QtWidgets.abi3.so               0x000000010414c52d sipQApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 237
18  QtCore                          0x0000000106c06d64 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 212 (qcoreapplication.cpp:1061)
19  QtWidgets                       0x000000010458c910 QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool, bool) + 896
20  QtWidgets                       0x00000001045e599f QWidgetWindow::handleMouseEvent(QMouseEvent*) + 3247 (qwidgetwindow.cpp:675)
21  QtWidgets                       0x00000001045e40a5 QWidgetWindow::event(QEvent*) + 229 (qwidgetwindow.cpp:295)
22  QtWidgets                       0x000000010458bfea QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 266 (qapplication.cpp:3673)
23  QtWidgets                       0x000000010458d476 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 598
24  QtWidgets.abi3.so               0x000000010414c52d sipQApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 237
25  QtCore                          0x0000000106c06d64 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 212 (qcoreapplication.cpp:1061)
26  QtGui                           0x0000000104be6ca5 QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::MouseEvent*) + 3397 (qguiapplication.cpp:2215)
27  QtGui                           0x0000000104bcbe5b QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 219 (qwindowsysteminterface.cpp:1181)
28  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0000000115504e00 QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::processPostedEvents() + 320 (qcocoaeventdispatcher.mm:907)
29  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0000000115505568 QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::postedEventsSourceCallback(void*) + 40
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000100087b21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000100087ac0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 103
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001000878d4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 209
33  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000100086740 __CFRunLoopRun + 1272
34  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000100085bd3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 499
35  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001097e265d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
36  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001097e22a9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
37  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001097e2127 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010527ceb4 _DPSNextEvent + 990
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010527b690 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1352
40  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010526d3ae -[NSApplication run] + 658
41  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x00000001155041cf QCocoaEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 2495 (qcocoaeventdispatcher.mm:438)
42  QtCore                          0x0000000106c02e0f QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 431 (atomic:929)
43  QtCore                          0x0000000106c07372 QCoreApplication::exec() + 130 (qcoreapplication.cpp:1369)
44  QtWidgets.abi3.so               0x000000010423e352 meth_QApplication_exec_(_object*, _object*) + 82
45  org.python.python               0x0000000100762d8d _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 749
46  org.python.python               0x0000000100762eb1 _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 49
47  org.python.python               0x00000001008360aa call_function + 762
48  org.python.python               0x000000010083d67e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29390
49  org.python.python               0x0000000100761367 function_code_fastcall + 135
50  org.python.python               0x000000010083604f call_function + 671
51  org.python.python               0x0000000100838843 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 9363
52  org.python.python               0x0000000100835740 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3088
53  org.python.python               0x0000000100835904 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
54  org.python.python               0x000000010087bd8e PyRun_FileExFlags + 206
55  org.python.python               0x000000010087c02f PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 447
56  org.python.python               0x000000010089a76d pymain_main + 2733
57  org.python.python               0x000000010089aafa _Py_UnixMain + 218
58  org.python.python               0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000101476818 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000101476818 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000101476818 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000101476818 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010141725a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001014175d0 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000100087d0b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 322
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001000868e7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1695
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000100085bd3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 499
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010541fa72 _NSEventThread + 132
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010147ae65 _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010147683b thread_start + 15

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff6240adc0  rcx: 0x00007fff5bffc878  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5bffc8a0  rsp: 0x00007fff5bffc878
   r8: 0x00000000000130a8   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007fff6240adc0  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x0000000102c034e0  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x000000010141d7fa  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x000000010141c95c
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```